# How to deny a host posting to my server with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl

I have a host posting using curl to my server where I held posted info.

now this is the host drops.gamekey.sa.com

I tried this

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from drops.gamekey.com
```

And this

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from gamekey.sa.com
```

And this

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 192.185.48.181
```

nothing seems to work, and I did this to check if it is working,

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

And it works. But what is the point of denying all. I want this specific website.

this website gamekey.sa.com is hosted at hostgator.com if that any relevant to the subject.

Comment: What do you mean by "posting to your server"? Is that web server directly making requests, or does it have an HTML form (or Javascript) which is directing users to post to your site, or something else?

Comment: @duskwuff it is using `curl` to post and get output results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your `Allow` directive?

If `Allow from all`, when using Order `Deny,Allow`, any host will also match the `Allow from all` directive and will be allowed, as stated in Apache's manual:

> **Deny,Allow**
>   First, all Deny directives are evaluated; if any match, the request is denied unless it also matches an Allow directive. Any requests which do not match any Allow or Deny directives are permitted.

That's why I would rather use the `Allow,Deny` order in this way:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from 192.185.48.181
```

> **Allow,Deny**
>   First, all Allow directives are evaluated; at least one must match, or the request is rejected. Next, all Deny directives are evaluated. If any matches, the request is rejected. Last, any requests which do not match an Allow or a Deny directive are denied by default.

Comment: Tried yours. still working. see this page drops.gamekey.sa.com/test.php

Comment: It says 'ERROR 204: Request failed.'?

Comment: I would log the request on the target website and see the request is not proxied. You'd have to adapt the denied IP.

Comment: I didn't understand. could you please explain?

Comment: Check the access log on the server where you defined the `Deny` rule and see if access is indeed from `192.185.48.181`

Comment: where I can find the `access log`?

Comment: found it, different IP. for some reason. use it and worked fine

Comment: Some hosts use different interfaces for inbound and outbound traffic. Never assume the IP associated with the domain you use to access it will be the same for outbound traffic.

Comment: It might change in the future. It's completely up to the server admin.